How to export data from route/web.php into controller function - Laravel
When i use redirect() method, i can use like
return redirect() -> route('name') -> with('data', 'value')
But, how can i use 'with' method on route file?
I want like this:
Route::name('Register')
-> controller(Register::class)
-> prefix('register')
-> group(function() {
    Route::name('.Interface')
    -> get('/', 'Interface');
    Route::name('.Action')
    -> post('/', 'Action')
    -> middleware([HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class])
    -> with('register.section', function() {
        if(Session::get('register.section') == 1) return 2;
        return 1;
    });
    Route::name('.EmailVerificationInterface')
    -> get('email-verification', 'EmailVerificationInterface');
    Route::name('.EmailVerificationProcess')
    -> post('email-verification', 'EmailVerificationProcess');
});

How can i use 'with' method in route file?

You can directly access session data inside your controller.
